# How can I run a Presto query find the index of an element in an array of rows

Tags: sql, google-analytics, presto

I have the following columns in a Presto table

| sku | product |
| --- | --- |
| 012345 | ['(productsku='012345', title='this title', ...)'] |

where the product column is an array of rows

How can I write a SQL query to find the index of the sku in the list of products (i.e.  like the productListPosition)?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to transform array of rows into array of productskus and use `array_position`:

```sql
WITH dataset(sku, product) AS (
    values
    (1, array[cast(ROW(1) as ROW(productsku INTEGER)),cast(ROW(2) as ROW(productsku INTEGER))]),
    (2, array[cast(ROW(1) as ROW(productsku INTEGER)),cast(ROW(2) as ROW(productsku INTEGER))]),
    (3, array[cast(ROW(1) as ROW(productsku INTEGER)),cast(ROW(2) as ROW(productsku INTEGER))])
)

select array_position(transform(product, r -> r.productsku), sku)
from dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 0 |